# Is grounding a logical relation?

Tags: metaphysics, grounding

Should we understand grounding relations as logical relations or as causal relations? Supervenience is a logical relation, for example, but I don't know what to say about grounding.

Comment: Can you give a reference claiming 'Supervenience is a logical relation' not causal?

Comment: None of the above. [Supervenience](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/supervenience/) is not a logical relation either. [SEP, Metaphysical Grounding](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/grounding/):"*It isn’t an identity claim... It isn’t a causal claim either, at least if by causation we mean what we normally mean when we use the term... Finally, the claim isn’t purely modal in character either... grounding is understood to be a form of constitutive (as opposed to causal or probabilistic) determination or explanation.*" It is often a metaphysical relation, just like supervenience.